# How update an embedded field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a MongoDB document I would like to update a specific field in the array, e.g., dealers > dealer3 > rating to a value of 1 for a specific object _id.  How would I update the field?

My document looks like the following:

```
{
        "_id" : "CARS1P01182016A0018789",
        "name" : "Acme Company",
        "dealers" : {
                "dealer1" : {
                        "units" : 1200,
                        "n" : 50,
                        "rating" : 0.05
                },
                "dealer2" : {
                        "n" : 20,
                        "rating" : 0
                },
                "dealer3" : {
                        "n" : 100,
                        "rating" : 0
                }
        },
        "status" : "active"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to specify the embedded document path in your update, together with the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** operator as follows:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": "CARS1P01182016A0018789" },
    {
        "$set": {
            "dealers.dealer3.rating": 1
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, just had a typo, I was doing a db.test.find instead of db.test.update.

db.test.update( { _id : "CARS1P01182016A0018789" }, { $set : { "dealers.dealer3.rating" : 1 } }  );

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular `$inc` operator and nest through your document with dot notation

```
db.collection.update (
         {_id: 'CARS1P01182016A0018789'}, 
         {'$inc':{"dealer.dealer3.rating" : 1} }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `$inc` operator and dot notation to update the field, `$inc` operator will increment the value of the field. `$set` will only set the value to a fixed value.

```
db.collection.update({"_id": "CARS1P01182016A0018789"},{$inc:{"dealer.dealer3.rating":1}})
```